# CSS display content from a class?

Tags: html, css

is it possible to display content of a specific class, using only css?

something like this:

```
.something-else:before {
  content: [class*="test"];
}
```

can't seem to get it to work.

Edit: I would like to show the content of a specific class:

```
<div class="test">Some text here</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do - show the contents of the class attribute? show the contents of the element/s with the class name? etc...

Comment: content of the class with specific class name <class="test">Sometext</class>

Comment: you can use data-attr with same element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Comment: from a class it  can be tricky if you have 2 container of them, should they be added ? So far, only javascript can do this.

Answer (score 2):

The support is minimal right now (FireFox only), but you can use the [`element()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element) CSS function to use one element as an image in another. It works with id and not class.

Example (currently only works on FF):

```css
.something-else::before {
  display: block;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 30vh;
  background: -moz-element(#test);
  border: 1px solid red;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="position: absolute; top: -1000px;">Some text here</div>

<div class="something-else"></div>
```